# ListView automatically Scrolls to bottom and stays at bottom itself

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a RelativeLayout and a ListView in that. I am using a custom layout and an adapter.

When the app is loaded, the focus is on top of the list item. When I scroll (even just a little), the list scrolls down to the bottom by itself. After that, when I try to scroll up, the list does not maintains the scroll position. It drops to bottom of the list.

*Layout:*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.javapapers.android.listview.ArrayAdapterListViewActivity">

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:transcriptMode="disabled"
 />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

*Activity:*

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends Activity {
private static final String TAG = "ScheduleActivity";

private MatchArrayAdapter matchArrayAdapter;
private ListView listView;

private static int colorIndex;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.schedule_layout);
    colorIndex = 0;
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    matchArrayAdapter = new MatchArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.match_layout);

    List<String[]> matchList = readData();
    for(String[] matchData:matchList ) {
        String teamA = matchData[0];
        String teamAFlagRes = matchData[1];
        String matchStart = matchData[2];
        String teamB = matchData[3];
        String teamBFlagRes = matchData[4];

        int teamAFlagResId = getResources().getIdentifier(teamAFlagRes, "drawable", "com.javapapers.android.customlistview.app");
        int teamBFlagResId = getResources().getIdentifier(teamBFlagRes, "drawable", "com.javapapers.android.customlistview.app");

        Match match = new Match(teamA,
                teamB,
                matchStart,
                teamAFlagResId,
                teamBFlagResId,
                getNextColor());
        matchArrayAdapter.add(match);
    }
}
```

*Adapter:*

```
public class MatchArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Match> {
private static final String TAG = "MatchArrayAdapter";
private List<Match> matchList = new ArrayList<Match>();

static class MatchViewHolder {
    ImageView teamAFlag;
    ImageView teamBFlag;
    TextView teamA;
    TextView teamB;
    TextView matchStart;
}

public MatchArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId);
}

@Override
public void add(Match object) {
    matchList.add(object);
    super.add(object);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    MatchViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.match_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new MatchViewHolder();
        viewHolder.teamAFlag = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamAFlag);
        viewHolder.teamBFlag = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamBFlag);
        viewHolder.teamA = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamA);
        viewHolder.teamB = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.teamB);
        viewHolder.matchStart = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.matchStart);
        row.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (MatchViewHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Match match = getItem(position);
    viewHolder.teamAFlag.setImageResource(match.getTeamAFlag());
    viewHolder.teamA.setText(match.getTeamA());
    viewHolder.matchStart.setText(match.getMatchStart());
    viewHolder.teamBFlag.setImageResource(match.getTeamBFlag());
    viewHolder.teamB.setText(match.getTeamB());
    row.setBackgroundResource(match.getMatchColor());
    return row;
}
```

Comment: My first thought is that using `layout_height="wrap_content"` on a ListView is unusual, what happens if you use `match_parent` instead?

Comment: No change in behaviour. Scrolls down to the bottom and stays.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with intel x86 emulator. I have changed to ARM EABI emulator and the problem is solved now.